# Defining derivate of a function

Tags: scilab, derivative

I'm developing a program to draw speed and power curves as a function of time, my only problem is that i do not know how to translate the equation: **dt / dv** into a program.

Here is the program:

```
// Caractéristique du véhicule 
Mv = input("Mv = ") // la masse de la voiture
S  = input("S = ") // la surface de la voiture
Cx = input("Cx = ") // Le coeficient de pénétration dans l'air
Cr= input ("Cr = ") // Le coeficient de roulement 
Dr= input("Dr = ") // Le diametre des roues 
r= input(" r = ") // Le rapport de réduction du réducteur 
alpha= input(" alpha = ")
nt= input(" nt = ")
omega= input(" omega = ") //La vitesse de rotation (rad/s)
pair= input(" P_air = ") //la masse volumique de l'air en Kg/m^3
g= input(" g = ")
//////////////////////////////


for t=1:195;
    if t<11
       v(t)=(1.92*t)-224.5;
       Pm(t)=v(t)*(Mv*(dv/dt)+(1/2)*pair* 
       (v(t)^2)*S*Cx+Mv*g*sin(alpha)+Mv*g*Cr*cos(alpha));
```

I just gave you the first line of the program, just to know how to translate **dv / dt** into a program.

I will be very grateful if you could help me because I really need it for my project.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the link to the math function you trying to write in Matlab.

Comment: it's : v(t)=(1.92*t)-224.5;

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about your velocity function is that it is only dependant on time and is also linear so you can differentiate it fairly easy. That is dv(t)/dt = 1.92. Your power function should look something like this:

```
Pm(t)=v(t)*(Mv*1.92+(1/2)*pair);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your v has a functional form which is easily differentiable, you don't need to construct dv/dt in the program, you already know what it is. For your specific case, you can use 1.92 in place of dv/dt.